# How to upload files and save to the projects folder location from client side

Tags: angular

In my angular2 project, I need to upload multiple files and save those files to the folder '**upload**' located on the location of the project.

I've googled a lot but those codes are related to saving the files to the database using node.js or express.

Is it possible to accomplish it from the client side itself using **angular2**?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You'll need to create an end point at your app or server and send a file to it using AngularJS

Comment: From the server side only we can save those files to the projects folder location.